# Returning zip file from JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, gzip

I wrote a simple JSP to return a zipped version of a JavaScript file if the request contains an Accept-Encoding header containing 'gzip', and the unzipped version otherwise.

```
<%@ page language="java"%>

<%
    boolean zipVersionRequired = false;
    try
    {
            String acceptEncodingHeader = request.getHeader("Accept-Encoding");

            if (acceptEncodingHeader != null && acceptEncodingHeader.indexOf("gzip") != -1)
            {
                    zipVersionRequired = true;
                    response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");        
            }
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
    }
    catch (java.lang.Throwable t)
    {
    }
%>

<% if (zipVersionRequired == true) {
%>
    <jsp:forward page="/files/zipped/f1.js.gz"/>
<% } else {
%>
<jsp:forward page="/files/unzipped/f1.js"/>
<%
}
%>
```

One thing of note is that I set the Content-Type to "text/javascript" yet the value of that response header according to my browser is "application/x-gzip" - not sure where that got set. The Content-Encoding response header is set to 'gzip'. In Chrome Developer Tools, the response itself looks like a bunch of strange symbols, so I assume the browser has not unzipped the response.

I have written a servlet to do the same job - it reads the content of either the zipped or unzipped file depending on the Accept-Encoding request header and writes the contents back to the client. That servlet works fine, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong in the JSP version.

I am using Tomcat web server but please don't suggest the compression=on setting on the connector as a solution to anything here as that is not an option in this case.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Get rid of pointless whitespace before your first <% since that can interfere with you setting the content type properly. (Because content type needs to be set before printing anything.) And using `<jsp:forward.../>` doesn't make sense here to me.  Shouldn't it be `<jsp:include.../>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, developerwjk, for your comment.

This is too long to add as a reply to your comment so posting as an answer (and there is an answer; see below).

I'd be interested to know why you (developerwjk) think jsp:include is more appropriate than jsp:forward. If I use jsp:include, I get an IllegalStateException. I think I understand the reason for that - the JSP servlet uses the PrintWriter, and when I include a gz file using jsp:include, the gz suffix is a recognized mime type, and recognized as a binary type, and therefore the OutputStream is opened, causing an IllegalStateException. That's just my guesswork.

So I went back using forward, eliminated all white space (I checked that in the generated Java) and got the same issue as originall posted - so the problem is not to do with whitespace in the jsp (not when using jsp:forward anyway).

Then I found the reason it is not working - it is the Content-Type header in the response. That is being set by Tomcat because of the file name extension (gz) to mime-type (application/x-gzip) mapping in the default web.xml file. When I rename my .gz file to .xxxxx, the Content-Type header in the response matches what I set it to (text/javascript) and the browser (Chrome) successfully unzips the response and runs the javascript. Of course I would add a mime-type mapping in my war's web.xml rather than use .xxxxx extension in any real solution.

One final thing - I would expect jsp:include (where the file included is the .xxxxx one) to work as long as the jsp contains no white space - it doesn't. I get no response content and this error (on Chrome):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

I'm still chewing that one over.

Paul